# Delete Chromedriver from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want to lower the version of ChromeDriver in my eclipse. For that I want to delete the Chromedriver from Eclipse. However when I try to delete the Chromedriver. I got an error "An exception have been caught while processing refractoring delete"  Reason: Problems encountered while  deleting resources. I don't know how to change the version of my ChromeDriver now.And may I know why this happens, What should I do know?(I am not able to replace Chromedriver of different versions as well in eclipse)

Comment: How did you land up with the `ChromeDriver` within `Eclipse`? Didn't you just provide the _absolute path_ of _ChromeDriver_ through _Eclipse_?

Comment: I have provided the relative path to chromedriver. But as it is put in eclipse through drag and drop, now I am not able to delete the chromedriver that I am using in Eclipse.

Comment: Where and How did you `drag_and_drop()` **chromedriver** within Eclipse? _Manually_ or through _Selenium_?

Comment: Manually I have dragged and drop , and then used the relative path :

Comment: String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src/test/java\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);

Comment: Did u try ending tasks in task manager

Comment: Actually in task manager, There are so many processes running through Chrome Driver that I cannot end each task separately, It will take much time.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, i am very late.

i just realized the solution by miyself about the same problem. If you have copied ChormeDriver into your package, then you have delete all instances of Chormedriver on the memory. To do that, you need to click on Task Manager (Cntrl+Alt+Del) -> Select Task Manager and search for all Chorme Driver(s) and delete these tasks from process on Task Manager. Before you do the above step, close Chrome Browser. Once you delete all those tasks from Task Manager, then go to Eclipse and delete ChromeDriver from pacakge.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the machine
2. From eclipse open system explorer
3. find `chromedriver.exe` and replace the `chromedriver.exe` with older or newer version.

Comment: Just followed your steps , Still not able to delete Chromedriver

Comment: After restarting the machine, do not open anything and try deleting/replacing  chromedriver.exe first. Then open eclipse.

Comment: After some attempts I left the option to delete that and instead use the absolute path for new chromedriver like this: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");